# Spring AOP only method with annotation

Tags: spring-aop, spring-annotations

I have this AOP  that run on all my application methods, but I want it to run only on methods that annotation with ProfileExecution annotation,
how can I do it using this xml

```
<bean id="profiler" class="com.mytest.ProfilerExecution" />


<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="profiler">

        <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethod" 
            expression="execution(public * *(..))" />
            <aop:around pointcut-ref="serviceMethod" method="profile"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following pointcut expression `@annotation(com.abc.xyz.ProfileExecution)` with `AND` operation to filter the methods.

So final xml should look like below

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="profiler">
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethod" 
            expression="execution(public * *(..)) and @annotation(com.abc.xyz.ProfileExecution)" />
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="serviceMethod" method="profile"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

*Make sure to include the fully qualified name of annotation in the expression else it won't work.*